# soup.prettify() giving weird output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the website mentioned in the code. I don't know why but soup.prettify() is giving me the output not so in proper format.

Here is the code:

```
    url_1 = 'https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html'
    page = requests.get(url_1)
    soup = bs(page.content,'lxml')
    soup.prettify()
```

It returns the output as shown in the image

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAvOm.png)

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

```
print(soup.prettify())
```

would return the code in a cleaner manner since print would actually execute the '\n' instead of showing it.